# How do I disable parking pages on non-existing domains? (name.com)

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, domain-parking

When I do

```
doesntexist.example.com
```

It shows a parking page rather than just not resolving (that's what I want). Is there anyway to stop name.com from redirecting my domains like that?

Comment: What did name.com support say when you asked them?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, no. If your DNS provider is doing this to you, then there's nothing you can do about it, because they're faking the true response.

There is only one way to avoid this. Ditch your DNS and use a different one. <s>[Google's is supposedly pretty good](http://code.google.com/speed/public-dns/) if you're located in North America (their latency is a bit too high for the rest of the world.</s>

> Configure your network settings to use
>   the IP addresses 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4
>   as your DNS servers or

In light of the comments below, I think I get your question now. I've had great milage from http://www.dnsmadeeasy.com/

Comment: The question is a bit unclear, but I think he means that he controls example.com, and his DNS host is redirecting non-existent subdomains of his domain.  So changing the DNS on the client wouldn't help, because Google would just go to the servers for example.com and run into the same problem.

Comment: Ooohh. Then get a better DNS provider is still the answer, but the context is different.